# Using extra features on Mac & iDevice supported headphones

Tags: 10.10, sound, apple, headphones, drivers

I bought some [headphones](http://www.scosche.com/consumer-tech/product/1862) and was wondering if I could find any drivers that could support the mic, the volume buttons, and playlist navigation button.

I am not positive, but the drivers used by the Apple headphones may work for this, but I don't know where I can find these kind of drivers.

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.